# I got blocked when i want to open a local file in javascript client side

Tags: javascript, file, xmlhttprequest, client-side-scripting

i want to open a local file by **Patch** in javascript client-side .
this is my code below -im using **xmlhttprequest** method :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function readfilebypatch(file)
    {
        var rawfile  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawfile.open("GET" , file , true);
        var all ;
        alert("in");
        rawfile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if ( rawfile.status === 200 || rawfile.status == 0)
            {
                all = rawfile.responseText;
                alert(all);
            }
        }
       //rawfile.send('0');
    }
    readfilebypatch("file:///c:/users/acer/desktop/tavasoli.txt");
</script>
```

so i got this error after **in** alert :

> ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/users/acer/desktop/tavasoli.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

andthis warning :

> [Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 1241ms

and this one :

> BASE64.HTML:32 GET file:///C:/users/acer/desktop/tavasoli.txt net::ERR_FAILED

so i know my browser ( chrome ) is blocking these kind of requests and i have to do this :
**https://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html**
but this doesnt work .
 **Note: is there other way to open file in javascript client side ?** 
thanks!

Comment: No, there is not. An XHR request to a `file:` URL does not make sense. An XHR implies that an HTTP server will respond, but `file:` URLs do not work that way.

Comment: i think here it is working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file @pointy